# Validacion AJV - Email - Regex

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, regex, schema

estoy trabajando con **AJV Schema** para corroborar que el tipo de dato recibido es correcto. Si bien la **clave** la verifica bien, la función que analiza el formato del **email** es ignorado. Alguna sugerencia?

```
const Ajv = require("ajv").default
const AjvFormats = require('ajv-formats');
const ajv = new Ajv()
AjvFormats(ajv);

const email = { email: '' }

const schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        email: {type: "string"}
    },
    required: ["email"]
}

function check(data){

    const emailRegex = new RegExp('/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/')
    ajv.addFormat('email-address', {
        validate: (format) => emailRegex.test(format)
    })

    const valid = ajv.validate(schema, data)
    !valid ? console.log(ajv.errors) : console.log(data)

}

check(email)
```

Comment: dentro de `check()`, `email` y `data` son `{ email: '' }`, y además `data` no lo usas.

Comment: Hice los cambios que ayer pasé por alto cuando subi esta publicación, pero no funciona. Justamente dejé a propósito el campo de email vacio para que salte a la primera un mensaje de error. En cambio, si la key email no está o está mal escrita funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema reside en que en el `schema` no estás definiendo explícitamente que la propiedad `email` tendrá un formato, solo que será de tipo string. Por lo que el `schema` debería ser definido de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        email: {type: 'string', format: 'email-format'}
    },
    required: ['email']
}
```

Luego entonces al hacer tu validación, deberías ser capaz de obtener el resultado  que esperas.

```
[{
  instancePath: "/email",
  schemaPath: "#/properties/email/format",
  keyword: "format",
  params: { format: "email-format" },
  message: "must match format \"email-format\""
}]
```

[Runkit](https://runkit.com/ricardo-dlc/ajv-formats-example) con el ejemplo funcionando como se espera y unas ligeras modificaciones.

**Edit:** Desconozco el funcionamiento a fondo de `addFormat`, pero revisando el [ejemplo de la documentación](https://ajv.js.org/guide/formats.html#user-defined-formats) noté que al usar una regex para un formato, la aplican directamente sin construirla con `RegExp()`. Entonces la parte de añadir el formato quedaría así:

```javascript
const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

ajv.addFormat('email-format', emailRegex);
```

Con el cambio anterior obtienes la siguiente salida:

```javascript
// { email: 'email' }:
// [{
//   instancePath: "/email",
//   schemaPath: "#/properties/email/format",
//   keyword: "format",
//   params: { format: "email-format" },
//   message: "must match format \"email-format\""
// }]

// { email: 'email@mail.com' }:
// { email: "email@mail.com" }

// { email: 'e mail@mail.com' }:
// [{
//   instancePath: "/email",
//   schemaPath: "#/properties/email/format",
//   keyword: "format",
//   params: { format: "email-format" },
//   message: "must match format \"email-format\""
// }]
```

Para estos casos básicos funciona, tienes que tener en cuenta que intentar validar un email usando solo una regex puede ser algo complejo, así que eso ya depende de la regex que utilices.

Comment: Hola Ricardo! Pensé que lo había solucionado pero ahora todo el tiempo me arroja el resultado de que el formato no es válido!

Comment: Puedes revisar mi actualización. También puedes checar el [runkit](https://runkit.com/ricardo-dlc/ajv-formats-example/2.0.0) actualizado.

Comment: Ahora si! Muy bueno Ricardo, muchísimas gracias por el aporte y la resolución. De paso también terminé mejorando la expresión regular: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/

Comment: Genial, un gusto poder haber ayudado. Solo como comentario, ojo con el cambio de tu regex, el correo `e mail@mail.com` debería ser marcado como inválido (debido al espacio).

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de ese detalle. Fenómeno!!